# How to change the Magento 2 email sender called Owner?

Tags: magento2, email

I'm receiving the emails from the sender called **Owner**, as you can see in this image below, how could I change it?

[image: Magento 2 email sender Owner]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to change it in **Stores > Configuration > General > Store Email Address**

[image: Magento 2 chaning email sender]